# What focal length to use for full-body photography of a chubby person?

Tags: portrait, focal-length

Recently I took pictures of someone that was slightly chubby. Close-ups using a 50mm lens went very well, but trying to get some distance in to get a full body shot were not really that satisfactory. Typically they turned out very unflattering because I could not get the necessary angle to hide aspects such as a slight double-chin. I probably would have had to be another half a metre higher than my subject to take a satisfactory shot, and I also don't want my subject to always have to sit down so we can get the angle right. 
Getting shots with a 24mm wide-angle lens was much easier but at the same time on some shots the proportions looked somewhat warped, so to me it seems like using a 24mm for full body photography is something better reserved for specific shots and not for general photography.

So essentially I want to know what focal length makes most sense. Is it better to go wider, despite the perspective distortions or pick a narrower focal length and step back, though I would not know how to properly get the slightly above eye level angled-down effect in that case.

Comment: With the same lens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qe3oJnFtA_k

Answer (score 1):

I can’t say which focal length is best because there really is no ‘best’.

I would probably shoot at 85mm or maybe a little longer. The longer focal length will help flatten your subject a bit.

Also for double chin issues, do not take the photo from down low. You want your camera at least level with, if not a hair higher than your subject’s chin/face.